# Handling JSON time object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using React DatePicker to handle timestamp creation in a form in react. I am able to create a timestamp and successfully post to server. The problem is when i try to retrieve the same object from server into a form. I get the following error

**RangeError: Invalid time value**

```
  368 | var originalDate = toDate(dirtyDate);
  369 | 
  370 | if (!isValid(originalDate)) {
> 371 |   throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
      | ^  372 | } // Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
  373 | // This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
  374 | // See an issue about UTC functions: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376
```

The function that seems to be throwing this error is as follows

```
async populateHotels() {
    try {
      const hotelSlug = this.props.match.params.slug;
      if (hotelSlug === "new-hotel") return;
      const { data: hotel } = await getHotel(hotelSlug);
      this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(hotel) });
    } catch (ex) {
      if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404) console.log("Problem");
      // this.props.history.replace("/notfound");
    }
  }
```

MaptoView Function

```
mapToViewModel(hotel) {
    return {
      checkin: new Date("1970-01-01" + hotel.checkin),
      checkout: new Date("1970-01-01" + hotel.checkout),
      policies: hotel.policies,
    };
  }
```

Time handling function

```
setCheckin = (time) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data.checkin = time;
    this.setState({
      data,
    });
  };
```

And finally the render function

```
                <DatePicker
                  className="form-control digits"
                  selected={this.state.data.checkin}
                  onChange={this.setCheckin}
                  showTimeSelect
                  showTimeSelectOnly
                  timeIntervals={30}
                  timeCaption="Time"
                  timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
                  dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss aa"
                  placeholderText="Checkin time"
                />
```

What could be the issue here please? Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here

```
mapToViewModel(hotel) {
    return {
      checkin: new Date("1970-01-01" + hotel.checkin),
      checkout: new Date("1970-01-01" + hotel.checkout),
      policies: hotel.policies,
    };
  }
```

I was not properly concatenating the date string. i used  javscript's `concat` and the error is gone. as shown `checkin: new Date(hotel.checkin.concat("1970-01-01")),`